# Robot Framework with Java (Hi-Fi library): can I use String keywords?

Tags: java, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework with Hi-Fi selenium-java implementation (https://github.com/Hi-Fi/robotframework-seleniumlibrary-java). But I need to use some of the keywords implemented in RF's "String" library (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html). Is there a way to do so in Java?

Otherwise: is there a way I can extend Hi-Fi's library and implement my own keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of [standard modules](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/) that are available in Robot Framework and should be available in any implementation.

1. BuiltIn
2. Collections
3. DateTime
4. Dialogs
5. OperatingSystem
6. Process
7. Remote
8. Screenshot
9. String
10. Telnet
11. XML

Comment: Yes, but these are for standard Robot Framework (Python). I'm using a Java library. I tried importing the String library and using "Strip String" but I'm getting "No keyword with name 'Strip String' found".

Comment: How did you call `Strip String`? Which version of RobotFramework do you use?

Comment: I'm using Hi-Fi's java implementation version 3.7.1.3. Actually, I changed the place where I called the library and now `Strip String` works. I was importing the library in the Settings section of my `__init__.robot` file (which lives in the same folder as my `Resources.robot` where I intend to use the keyword). I had the impression that \__init\__ was the place to put general settings and it got automatically imported. Isn't that so? Since I made the call to `Library  String` within the "Settings" section of `Resources.robot` it works now, but still not sure why it didn't work in \__init\__.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. In the Robot Framework guide there is a specific section on this that explains what the [initialisation file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) does. As you discovered it does not behave like the init of a class.